# Cakephp:How do i retrieve specific rows in an array

Tags: cakephp

Hi guys i have my array below and i want to retrieve two rows:as     programme_code=>programme_name

My array is below,please help

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'ProgrammeRequirementsSubject' => array(
        'programme_code' => 'HEN',
        'programme_name' => 'Electrical Engineering'
    )
)
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $array[0]['ProgrammeRequirementsSubject']['programme_code'],
     '=>',
     $array[0]['ProgrammeRequirementsSubject']['programme_name'];
```

Comment: thanx man,now i'm can move forward